# TableView open´s splitview view´s

Tags: ios, ipad, uitableview, uisplitviewcontroller

Hi
anybody can explain of how to show a splitview when I tap a row from a cell??
or a tutorial of it??

I have a tableview, and i want to display information about that cell in a splitview.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a tutorial for that, since you're not supposed to do that.

The split view controller is supposed to be the root view controller of your application, so if you want a pushable split view controller you'll have to write it yourself (or possibly find an open source one).

Answer (score 0):

I want to implement an app that when it press a row from a table, it will open a splitviewcontroller that show the information
about the selected cell in the "detail´s splitview" , and all the info of the table  in the "rootview".

I have copy to my project the

- DetalviewController.h/m
- RootViewController.h/m
- DetailView.Xib

files from the splitview template.

And add this code to my tableviewcontroller:

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{

```
  //Initialize the controller.

 if(split == nil)

 split = [[RootViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"split" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];


 //Pass the current row number to the sub view controller.

     split.number = indexPath.row;



   //here is my problem, i cant add the new view, and it crash
 [self.view addSubview:[split view]];
```

}

```
enter code here
```